# Plotting an Expression that is a Summation in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I was solving the Helmholtz equation using Mathematica and got as an output an expression which is a summation. I first want to turn this expression into a function of $x$ and $y$. I then want to use Mathematica to plot this function in the domain $D=[-3,3] \times [-3,3]$ but I cannot figure out how to do this. My code to produce the expression is:

```
eqn = Laplacian[bottom[x, y], {x, y}] + bottom[x, y] == 0;
bc4 = {bottom[-3, y] == 0, bottom[3, y] == 0, 
     bottom[x, -3] == Sin[(\[Pi]x)/6] - Csc[3/Sqrt[2]] Sin[x/Sqrt[2]], 
     bottom[x, 3] == 0};
sol4 = DSolveValue[{eqn, bc4}, bottom[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

This outputs:

```
Inactive[Sum][-((2 Csch[Sqrt[-36 + \[Pi]^2 K[1]^2]] ((-1)^K[1] (1 + 
      (-1)^K[1]) \[Pi]^2 K[1]^2 - (-1 + (-1)^K[1]) (-18 + \[Pi]^2 K[1]^2) 
      Sin[\[Pi]x/6]) Sin[1/6 \[Pi] (3 + x) K[1]] Sinh[1/6 (-3 + y) Sqrt[-36 
      + \[Pi]^2 K[1]^2]])/(\[Pi] K[1] (-18 + \[Pi]^2 K[1]^2))), {K[1], 1, \ 
      [Infinity]}]
```

Now I tried using:

```
ans[x_,y_] = Evaluate[sol4]; 
Plot3D[answer, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

But the plot that's produced just shows nothing. I'm assuming my issue is that the Evaluate function isn't doing what I want it to do but I'm not quite sure what else to use - any thoughts? Do I need to activate the summation?

Comment: I don't expect that infinite sum to be easily plottable as is. Instead, I would suggest doing something like `Plot3D[Evaluate[Activate[sol4 /. Infinity -> 10]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]` instead to see an approximation.

Comment: hmm I'm still getting just a blank plot

Comment: Your `bottom[x, -3]` condition as currently written is faulty, apparently. Don't forget to separate multiplied variables with a space! `bottom[x, -3] == Sin[(π x)/6] - Csc[3/Sqrt[2]] Sin[x/Sqrt[2]]`

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, I just edited that and still nothing changed though.

Comment: After you correct the Pix to  Pi x, the summation includes a $\frac{1}{1-K[1]^2}$ term with K[1] the summation index so it's indeterminate when K[1]=1.  Also, the sum is "inactivated" for some reason I don't know.  So I first explicitly change K[1]=1 to just k=2 for now (don't know how that would change the solution though), change the upper limit to say 100, and then activate it:

    mySol = sol4 /. {K[1] -> k, \[Infinity] -> 100}
    mySol[[2]] = {k, 2, 100}
    myf[x_, y_] = Activate@mySol;
    Plot3D[myf[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]  And I get a plot which looks reasonable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

another option instead of skipping the first term is to take its real part. (can easily change this below to takes its absolute value also and compare).

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = Laplacian[bottom[x, y], {x, y}] + bottom[x, y] == 0;
bc4 = {bottom[-3, y] == 0, bottom[3, y] == 0, 
   bottom[x, -3] == Sin[(Pi*x)/6] - Csc[3/Sqrt[2]] Sin[x/Sqrt[2]], 
   bottom[x, 3] == 0};
sol4 = DSolveValue[{eqn, bc4}, bottom[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify;
sol4 = sol4 /. K[1] -> n;
lim = Limit[sol4[[1]], n -> 1];
sol = Sum[Piecewise[{{Re[lim], n == 1}, {sol4[[1]], n > 1}}], {n, 1,10}];

p1 = Plot3D[sol, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
       PlotLabel -> "Analytical solution", ImageSize -> 300];

solN = NDSolve[{eqn, bc4}, bottom, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
p2 = Plot3D[Evaluate[bottom[x, y] /. solN], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
      PlotLabel -> "numerical solution", ImageSize -> 300];

Grid[{{p1, p2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Increase the summation index to get more accurate analytical solution. Now it uses only 10 terms.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I propose:

The solution is:

$$
\tiny
\underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}-\frac{2 \left((-1)^{K[1]}+1\right) K[1] \left(\frac{\pi ^2 (-1)^{K[1]}}{\pi ^2 K[1]^2-18}+\frac{1}{1-K[1]^2}\right) \text{csch}\left(\sqrt{\pi ^2 K[1]^2-36}\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  (x+3) K[1]\right) \sinh \left(\frac{1}{6} (y-3) \sqrt{\pi ^2 K[1]^2-36}\right)}{\pi }
$$

and note there is the term $\frac{1}{1-K[1]^2}$ with $K[1]$ the summation index which is indeterminate at $K[1]=1$.  However, the limit at $K[1]=1$ exists:

$$
\lim_{K[1]->1} \text{sol4}=i \csc \left(\sqrt{36-\pi ^2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{6}\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{36-\pi ^2} (y-3)\right)
$$

so that we we are left with a complex solution but the PDE is linear so the real and imaginary components of sol4 are solutions.  So I propose taking the sum starting with k=2 as one solution (the real component), and the imaginary component of the limit above as a second solution.  Note back-substituting the imaginary component of that limit also satisfies the PDE.

Code for real sol:

```
eqn = Laplacian[bottom[x, y], {x, y}] + bottom[x, y] == 0;
bc4 = {bottom[-3, y] == 0, bottom[3, y] == 0, 
   bottom[x, -3] == Sin[(\[Pi] x)/6] - Csc[3/Sqrt[2]] Sin[x/Sqrt[2]], 
   bottom[x, 3] == 0};
sol4 = DSolveValue[{eqn, bc4}, bottom[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify
mySol = sol4 /. {K[1] -> k, \[Infinity] -> 100}
mySol[[2]] = {k, 2, 100}
myF[x_, y_] = Activate@mySol;
Plot3D[myF[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```